# Extracting plain text from an html content variable in HAML

Tags: html, haml, hamlc

I'm trying to extract the plain text from some HTML content in HAML. For example, if I have this HTML in a variable called message.content:

```
Hi, this is a <strong>test</strong> message!
```

I have a HAML line like this:

```
%p= message.content
```

And I want this as the output:

```
<p>
  Hi, this is a test message!
</p>
```

Is there any possible way I can do it? I have looked at `!=` but it interprets the HTML, and also the `:plain` filter, but no luck. any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know a HAML helper for this purpose and you have to make use of an external helper or by using a RegExp. I know RegExp is not really the tool of choice for HTML processing, but it works fine in simple cases:

```
%p= message.content.replace(/<\/?\w+\/?>/g, '')
```

Since you added the `hamlc` tag and you might want this solution to work in the browser, you can use jQuery to extract the text content:

```
%p= $(message.content).text()
```

Comment: Yeah, I ended up doing it with jQuery like you mentioned. I think it's safer than the RegExp, Thanks!.